# How can I get the user's email address in google apps?

Tags: php, google-plus, access-token

How can I get the user's email address if I have the *access token* of that user in my **google plus** apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the user's email address requires additional authorization. You will need to add the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope and can then use the userinfo endpoint to request the information. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps it helps
https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#resource

Comment: this link is dead